# Python: how to convert text data types in one column to be able to perform some analysis (such as counts)

Tags: python, pandas, object, types

I'm trying to count the number of times something comes up in one column, and group it by another.  For example, I have the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\genre_testing.csv")
```

This gives me the following data example set:

[image]

What I would like to be able to do later is count the number of "Adventure" shows/movies, and have both mandalorian and zombieland counted.  I believe the first issue is that both columns are stored as `objects`  but I may need them as arrays?

Using something like `df.groupby('genre')['show_name'].nunique()` provides the full object rather than the elements, which is what I'm looking for. Any advice on where to start? Thanks!

Comment: You may wish to use df['genre'].str.split(',') to split the genre column into a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentionned, you can use `.str.split(',')` to get the genre as a list, but to further that response, once you have `split` you can `explode` your dataframe to have a dataframe more suited for filtering, counting, ...

```py
>>> data = pandas.DataFrame(data=[["mandalorian", "Adventure,Action,Sci-Fi"], ["zombieland", "Comedy,Adventure,Action"]], columns=["show_name", "genre"])
>>> data
     show_name                    genre
0  mandalorian  Adventure,Action,Sci-Fi
1   zombieland  Comedy,Adventure,Action
>>> data['genre'] = data['genre'].str.split(',')
>>> data
     show_name                        genre
0  mandalorian  [Adventure, Action, Sci-Fi]
1   zombieland  [Comedy, Adventure, Action]
>>> data = data.explode('genre')
>>> data
     show_name      genre
0  mandalorian  Adventure
0  mandalorian     Action
0  mandalorian     Sci-Fi
1   zombieland     Comedy
1   zombieland  Adventure
1   zombieland     Action
>>> data[data['genre'] == 'Adventure']['show_name']
0    mandalorian
1     zombieland
>>> data.groupby('genre')['show_name'].nunique()
genre
Action       2
Adventure    2
Comedy       1
Sci-Fi       1
Name: show_name, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

There's already a thing for this which should be pretty easy to use.

```
df_coded = df['genre'].str.get_dummies(sep=",")
df_coded['show_name'] = df['show_name']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative that might put you on the way. Assume your `df` is defined this way

```
d = {'Show':["Zombieland","Madalorian","Star Wars","Spiderman"],'genre':["Adventure,SciFi", "Adventure,SciFi,Action","SciFi,Action","Comedy"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Which gives you

```
    Show        genre
0   Zombieland  Adventure,SciFi
1   Madalorian  Adventure,SciFi,Action
2   Star Wars   SciFi,Action
3   Spiderman   Comedy
```

What you wish is to subset this `df` by choosing only those rows for which the `genre` column contains, say `Action`. You can do this this way:

```
df2 =df[df.genre.astype(str).str.contains('Action')]
```

which gives

```
    Show        genre
1   Madalorian  Adventure,SciFi,Action
2   Star Wars   SciFi,Action
```

You can then do subsetting on that or simply do a row count `count_row = df2.shape[0]`